# Find consecutive dates every 5 days in momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a calendar where a user must mark a date 4 times. Let's assume that for every day the user could mark and return the following object:

```
{
 date: '2018-01-10',
 dots: [{
         color: 'blue',
         key: 'markOne'
        }, 
        {
         color: 'red',
         key: 'markTwo'
        },
        {
         color: 'black',
         key: 'markThree'
        }, 
        {
         color: 'yellow',
         key: 'markFour'
        }
       ] 
},
{
 date: '2018-02-10',
 dots: [{
         color: 'blue',
         key: 'markOne'
        }, 
        {
         color: 'red',
         key: 'markTwo'
        },
        {
         color: 'black',
         key: 'markThree'
        }, 
        {
         color: 'yellow',
         key: 'markFour'
        }
       ]
},
{
 date: '2018-03-10',
 dots: [{
         color: 'blue',
         key: 'markOne'
        }, 
        {
         color: 'blue',
         key: 'markTwo'
        },
        {
         color: 'black',
         key: 'markThree'
        }, 
        null
       ]
},
{...day4},
{...day5 and so on}
```

I need to show a local notification to the user only if the `date` is consecutive for 5 days and only if `dots` don't have a `null` object.

So let's assume the user started marking (all 4 dots) at `2018-01-10` when he marks all 4 dots until `2018-05-10` then a local notification should be shown (that's another logic that I've already implemented).

If dates are consecutive but `dots` array has at least one `null` then it should not send a notification.

The dates should be broken down every 5 days, so every `5,10,15,20,25,30` of the month a different notification should be shown from:

```
const notificationsEveryFiveDays = [
 {day5: 'day 5 notification'},
 {day10: 'day 10 notification'},
 {day15: 'day15 notification'},
 {day20: 'day20 notification'},
 {day25: 'day25 notification'},
 {day30: 'day 30 notification'}
];
```

So far I've managed to get all dates and manipulate the object keys to return a sorted by date array.

```
export const MarkedDates = () => {
  MyStorage.getItem('markedDates').then((items) => {
    if (items) {
        let dates = _.map(items, (val, id) => {
            return {...val, date: id};
        });
        let sortedDates = _.sortBy(dates, 'date');
        console.log(sortedDates);
    }
});
```

};

I'm trying to use `moment-range` but I can't figure out how to check if all `dates` are consecutive and `dots` don't contain `null`. It's a tough problem to solve!

Comment: A date format of YYYY-DD-MM is confusing to humans and has no reason to exist. Please consider changing it to  YYY-MM-DD which is widely understood and would make life much simpler. It seems the 31st of the month will never have a notification.

Comment: I totally agree, but this is how `wix-react-native-calendars` wants the date format. The end user is seing a normal date.

Comment: @RobG, my bad, they're using YYYY-MM-DD, I've typed (by hand) the wrong format in the question. From their github repo: `Parameters that require date types accept YYYY-MM-DD formated datestrings, JavaScript date objects, calendar objects and UTC timestamps.`

Comment: That's good to know. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assumming you are using the date format YYYY-DD-MM. (haven't seen that one before)

My approach is to first sort the list and remove anything with null dots since they don't count as consecutive days anyway. Afterwards we start at the minimum day and go through the list and check if a single day has passed since the last entry. When there are 5 consecutive days add the list of consectutive days to the consecutive array.

```js
const dates = [
{
 date: '2018-02-10',
 dots: [{color: 'yellow', key: 'markFour' } ]
},
{
 date: '2018-01-10',
 dots: [ { color: 'yellow', key: 'markFour' } ] 
},
{
 date: '2018-03-10',
 dots: [{ color: 'black', key: 'markThree' }]
},
{
  date: '2018-04-10',
  dots: [{color: "blue", key: 'markOne'}]
},
{
  date: '2018-05-10',
  dots: [{color: "blue", key: 'markOne'}]
}]

// if there is a null then do nothing. Let get that check out of the way first
const dotsHasNull = dates.filter(pair => (pair.dots.filter(dot => dot == null) ).length).length != 0


const sortedDates = dates.map(pair => { 
  // convert date to moment date to use the diff function later
  return {date: moment(pair.date, "YYYY-DD-MM"), dots: pair.dots} 
})
.filter( (pair) => {
 // filter out all days that contain null dots 
 // this is done to handle a case where days 1-7 are consecutive but day 1 contain a null dot, which would discard the entire range 
 // we want it to create a range from 2-7 instead.
 return pair.dots.filter(dot => dot == null).length == 0
 // Maybe you want it to discard the entire range if the range contains a dot, then move this check to after we have found the ranges.
})
.sort((a,b) => a.date.valueOf() - b.date.valueOf() ) // there are probably more efficient sorting methods:)


var consecutivePairs = [];

var currentConsecutive = [];

sortedDates.forEach(pair => {
  if (currentConsecutive.length == 0) {
    currentConsecutive.push(pair)
    return
  }
  const lastConsecutivePair = currentConsecutive[currentConsecutive.length -1];
  // as long as only one day has passed then keep adding to the list
  if (pair.date.diff(lastConsecutivePair.date, 'days') == 1) {
   currentConsecutive.push(pair)
  } else {
   // start with an array containing the current pair because otherwise we might skip some days
   currentConsecutive = [pair];
  }
  if (currentConsecutive.length == 5) {
   // when we have a range that is atleast 5 days long that add it to 
 consecutivePairs.push(currentConsecutive)
  }
})

consecutivePairs.forEach(consecutive => {
 // sounds like you have some specific requirements for the the notification
 // so you probably have to replace this

 // find every 5 days
 const mark = consecutive.length - (consecutive.length % 5)
 console.log("consecutive days notifications: ", "day " + mark + " notification");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Hope this solves you problem.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i wanted, when I'm done with local notifications I'll update the question with the final solution.